# Unable to generate and align looped boxes in an axis co-ordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

I am trying to generate set of boxes (using loops) inside a coordinate system. Here are my MWEe:

#### MWE1

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,
  xmax=6,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=4,
  axis on top,
  xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
  ytick={1,2,3},
  yticklabels={A,B,C},
  xlabel={X axis},
  ylabel={Y axis},
  ]

  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
      \filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
    }
  }  
  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \x
,\y
l.24 \end{axis}
```

#### MWE2

I changed my approach and tried:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
      \filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
    }
  }  
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,
  xmax=6,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=4,
  xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
  ytick={1,2,3},
  yticklabels={A,B,C},
  xlabel={X axis},
  ylabel={Y axis},
  ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And got an output:

[image]

Where the boxes do not properly align with the coordinate system.

Why are the boxes unable to inherit the coordinate system of the pgfplots? How do I get them to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `\addplot` with the squares being the marks. Using the `/.list` handler allows one to build up the coordinate list through loops without having to use global macros.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
    add x/.code={\edef\tmp{\tmp(#1,\y)}},
    add y/.code={\edef\y{#1}\tikzset{add x/.list={1,...,3}}}]
  \edef\tmp{}  
  \tikzset{add y/.list={1,...,3}}
  
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,
  xmax=6,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=4,
  xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
  ytick={1,2,3},
  yticklabels={A,B,C},
  xlabel={X axis},
  ylabel={Y axis},
  ]
  \addplot[only marks,mark=square,mark size=3mm] coordinates{\tmp};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

To have the boxes aligned with the coordinate system of the `axis` enviroment, you need to draw them inside the `axis` environment (or somehow grab the values of *x* and *y* from within the `axis` environment to the outside). Inside of the `axis` environment, you can use `\coordinate (0.5,0.5);` (without unit) to place a coordinate at the relevant axis coordinates.

One drawback, however, is that `\foreach` loops behave a bit different inside the `axis` environment and you need to handle the expansion order explicitly. This can be achieved using an `\edef\temp{\noexpand...}\temp` construct like shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,
  xmax=6,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=4,
  xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
  ytick={1,2,3},
  yticklabels={A,B,C},
  xlabel={X axis},
  ylabel={Y axis},
  ]
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5} {
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3} {
      \edef\mytemp{
        \noexpand\filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
      }\mytemp
    }
  }  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What does this strange construct do? Let's look at it in detail:

```
\edef\mytemp{
    \noexpand\filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
}\mytemp
```

We define an exandable macro `\mytemp` which has the definition as stated between the following pair of curly braces, and then call it immediately after having defined it. In the definition we make sure that first `\x` and `\y` are expanded to the relevant values and only then the `\filldraw` macro is called that uses these two macros. This way, we make sure that the expansion order is correct.

---

You probably want the rectangles centered at the relevant axis coordinate. To achieve this, you would need to shift the lower left coordinate halfways down and to the left:

```
\filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] 
    ([shift={(-0.25cm,-0.25cm)}]\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
```

Or you could use nodes which are aligned at their center by default:

```
\node[draw=black, fill=white, text width=0.5cm, text height=0.5cm, inner sep=0pt] 
    at (\x,\y) {};
```

Comment: Hello @Jasper, Thanks for your solution. I notice that the center of the squares are not aligned to the coordinate axis. Is that again a consequence of using loops in the axis setup?

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten No, this is a consequence of your definition how the rectangles are drawn: You say `(\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm)`, so one of the corners sits excaclty at the relevant coordinate and the other (opposite one) is half a centimeter upwards and to the right.

Comment: If you want to have them centered on the coordinates, you would need to do something like `\filldraw[draw=black, fill=white] ([shift={(-0.25cm,-0.25cm)}]\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);` or use rectangular `\node`s. with appropriate width and height (since they are aligned at their center by default) But this has really nothing to do with your setup inside the `axis` environment.

Comment: thanks for your solution.